# SketchFlow - Merge and Report Multiple users feedback

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend-3

I'm using Microsoft Elements 3 SketchFlow to get user feedback, but how can I merge them together or at least print them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the feedback files (*.feedback) into your Expression Blend project. This is done by clicking the + in the feedback window. Then as you view each page of your application the feedback will be displayed. There is a dropdown to select the feedback of each user.

As far as I can tell there is no way to summarise or export the feedback in a printable format. You can view the files in a text editor but it is just xml and not particularly readable.